# Iterating over a list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm a complete novice in MongoDB and I'm trying to delete some entries from a collection day by day. I have to do it day by day coz the collection is huge and removing by month times out. Here's an example code I have:

```
days = ['2018-04-01-day','2018-04-02-day','2018-04-03-day','2018-04-04-day','2018-04-05-day','2018-04-06-day','2018-04-07-day','2018-04-08-day','2018-04-09-day','2018-04-10-day','2018-04-11-day','2018-04-12-day','2018-04-13-day','2018-04-14-day','2018-04-15-day','2018-04-16-day','2018-04-17-day','2018-04-18-day','2018-04-19-day','2018-04-20-day','2018-04-21-day','2018-04-22-day','2018-04-23-day','2018-04-24-day','2018-04-25-day','2018-04-26-day','2018-04-27-day','2018-04-28-day','2018-04-29-day','2018-04-30-day']
var day;
for(day of days)
    {
        print(day)
        db.<colln>.remove
        (
            { 'time_bucket': day },
            { 'URL':/https:\/\/abc.com/}
        )
    }
```

The above code executes, but only gives me the following:

```
     2018-04-06-day
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })
```

I would have expected to atleast see all the dates printed, but even that's not happening.

I tried other methods using UTC date methods and they didn't seem to work as well.

I am able to make the following code work on a smaller collection:

```
db.<small colln>.remove(
    { 'time_bucket': '2018-04-month' },
    { 'URL':/https:\/\/abc.com/}
    )
```

But the above code (removing by month) won't work for a larger collection, which is why I'm forced to do it day by day, by creating an array for multiple days. I know it's not the most efficient method, but I just need to make it work anyhow.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a few sample docs?

Comment: You should **never** store date/time values as string, it's a design flaw. Store proper `Date` objects, mongo shell provides a build-in alias, e.g. `ISODate("2018-01-01T00:00:00Z")`

Answer (score 0):

`for(var day in days)` will iterate through indexes of your array, producing

```
for(var day in days){ print (day) }
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

I believe you meant to use `for(var day of days)`:

```
for(var day of days){ print (day) }
2018-04-01-day
2018-04-02-day
2018-04-03-day
2018-04-04-day
2018-04-05-day
2018-04-06-day
```

Just wanted to add a few more details. I have tested the following on my local MongoDB 4.2 on this collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6053e2f7acf8d9b7cc48adf0"), "name" : "test 4", "time_bucket" : "2018-04-03-day" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6053e4ccacf8d9b7cc48adf1"), "name" : "test", "time_bucket" : "2018-04-01-day" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6053e4d3acf8d9b7cc48adf2"), "name" : "test 1", "time_bucket" : "2018-04-01-day" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6053e4ddacf8d9b7cc48adf3"), "name" : "test 34", "time_bucket" : "2018-04-02-day" }
```

```
const days = ['2018-04-01-day','2018-04-02-day']
for(let day of days){ db.testcol.remove( { 'time_bucket': day }) }
```

After executing it, the collection looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6053e2f7acf8d9b7cc48adf0"), "name" : "test 4", "time_bucket" : "2018-04-03-day" }
```

So everything appears to work as intended.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, but I get this error even after changing `in` to `of` : `[js] ReferenceError: day is not defined :`

Comment: When I execute your code above, it executes properly. But when I have a MongoDB command to `remove`, then it's giving me `[js] ReferenceError: day is not defined :`

Comment: @Patthebug Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: The version is 4.2.2

Comment: I was able to solve that error, but I now have a new problem. I am working on updating the question so you have more context.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: I saw that you added more detail to your answer, Thanks so much for that. I tried your new code as well, and it gives me: `2018-04-06-day
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 0 })`

Comment: That's because the query does not match anything. Try running a `find` with the same exact query to see if the db actually matches any documents.